# Why change color to yellow not working with spriteRenderer programically in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I have a flower of which the petals are individually from the stalk:

[image]

I have no problem to change the petals to green or black with following script:

```
private void Start()
{
    flower = transform.GetChild(transform.childCount - 1).gameObject;
    if (Random.Range(0, 1.0f) < 0.5f)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < flower.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            flower.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;// Color.yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But what is weird is that the color will not change to yellow with this:

```
flower.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.yellow;
```

Note that, the `Random.range()` is not the problem. It just couldn't change to yellow/ or white, but colors such as `black`, `green` will be ok.

And if you may forgive me to ask another question, is the color representation of `rgba` from `0-1` is that of in Photoshop representation 0-255 divided by 255?
Such that a color `RGBA(255,255,1,255)` will be `Color(255/255.0, 255/255.0, 1/255.0, 255/255.0)` which will come to `Color(1.0f,1.0f,0.00001f, 1.0f)` in Unity?

FYI, the attribute of the petals' spriteRenderer is as following, and I use the `Sprite-Default` material:
[image]

### EDIT:

Add the raw sprite sheet as required by comment:

[image]

Comment: First of all, can you put a link to the image(flower) you are trying to change its color? Secondly, what happens when you attempt to change the color to yellow from the Editor instead of script? Does that work?  *I don't believe that yellow is not changing. You are doing something wrong!*

Comment: @Programmer I have added the sprite sheet to the edit, check that out :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the petals of the flower sprite white. (i.e change them in your sprite editing software, NOT in Unity). This will allow you to change the color of the sprite in the editor.

To check this, try just changing the color of the Sprite Renderer component to yellow in the inspector. It should still be red. Also check if the Sprite Renderer component's color field is yellow at run time. This will allow you to be certain that the code is working.

The problem is not your code; the problem is how the sprite's shader works. The `sprite-default` shader works by multiplying the `color` field that you are changing by the actual RGB value of the sprite. If the value of one of the RGB fields is 0 in the sprite's texture then multiplying it by some value will mean that it is still 0. I think that is what is happening for you.

You can see this happening by importing a pure red sprite and then trying to change the color of it in the inspector. It will just turn black.

If you are curious, you can download the source code for Unity's built in shaders [Here](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive).

Comment: Thanks, Danny, it seems to make sense, no wonder that the `Color()` take arguments from 0 to 1, and the default Color Macro such as `Color.green` is kind of misleading then.

Comment: yes, the static property `Color.green` is just an alias for `Color(0,1,0,1)`. All Color objects take values between 0 and 1 which may be confusing if you are used to using RGB values between 0 and 255. You seem to have worked out that dividing by 255 gets the values you need though.